# How to remove part of string json in python

Tags: python, json

I have a crawler with Python, my function get script with dataLayer and transform in string to format and convert to json.

This is dataLayer:

```
dataLayer = [{

    "site": {
        "isMobile": false,
        "source": (function() {
            var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase();
            var source = "web";
            resultMatch = userAgent.match(/\[olx-source\/(\w+);/);
            if (resultMatch) {
                [, source] = resultMatch;
            }
            return source;
        })()
    },
    "page": {
        "pageType": "ad_detail",
        "detail": {
            "parent_category_id": "2000",
            "category_id": "2020",
            "state_id": "2",
            "region_id": "31",

            "ad_id": "354269527",
            "list_id": "295567499",
            "city_id": "9190",
            "zipcode":"32146045",

        },

        "adDetail": {
            "adID": "354269527",
            "listID": "295567499",
            "sellerName": "Glauber Marlon",
            "adDate": "2017-01-23 18:35:26",
        },

    },
    "session": {
        "user": {
            "userID": "",
            "loginType": ""
        }
    },

    "pageType": "Ad_detail",
    "abtestingEnable" : "1",



// Listing information

"listingCategory": "2020",


// Ad information
"adId": "354269527",
"state": "2",
"region": "31",
"category": "2020",

"pictures": "14",
"listId": "295567499",

//Account Information

"loggedUser":"0",

"referrer": "",

//User Information


}];
```

This my function for format and convert in Json:

```
s = page_ad.findAll('script')[25].text.replace('\'', '"')
// if print s this line and put in JsonLint show error in function. 
s = re.search(r'\{.+\}', s, re.DOTALL).group() # get json data
s = re.sub(r'//.+\n', '', s) # replace comment
s = re.sub(r'\s+', '', s) # strip whitspace
s = re.sub(r',}', '}', s) # get rid of last , in the dict

dataLayer = json.loads(s)
```

This is json before convert:

```
{  
    "site":{  
        "isMobile":false,
        "source":(function()      {  
            varuserAgent=navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase();varsource="web";resultMatch=userAgent.match(/\         [  
                olx-source\/(\w+);/);if(resultMatch)            {  
                [  
                ,
                source
                ]               =resultMatch;
            }            returnsource;
        }         )()
    },
    "page":{  
        "pageType":"ad_detail",
        "detail":{  
            "parent_category_id":"2000",
            "category_id":"2020",
            "state_id":"2",
            "region_id":"31",
            "ad_id":"354269527",
            "list_id":"295567499",
            "city_id":"9190",
            "zipcode":"32146045"
        },
        "adDetail":{  
            "adID":"354269527",
            "listID":"295567499",
            "sellerName":"GlauberMarlon",
            "adDate":"2017-01-2318:35:26"
        }
    },
    "session":{  
        "user":{  
            "userID":"",
            "loginType":""
        }
    },
    "pageType":"Ad_detail",
    "abtestingEnable":"1",
    "listingCategory":"2020",
    "adId":"354269527",
    "state":"2",
    "region":"31",
    "category":"2020",
    "pictures":"14",
    "listId":"295567499",
    "loggedUser":"0",
    "referrer":""
}
```

I want remove the index "site" Where is the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler_olx_0.1.py", line 182, in <module>
    run(link_base)
  File "crawler_olx_0.1.py", line 52, in run
    vehicleInformation = getVehicleInformation(page_ad)
  File "crawler_olx_0.1.py", line 81, in getVehicleInformation
    dataLayer = json.loads(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No... do not edit html/xml/json/... with regexes are string replacement. These are context-free languages. Regexes are made for regular languages.

Comment: "Where is the error" is a very good question; where does your computer say it is?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more simple to make Javascript output a valid json from its object?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to execute javascript while scraping (Selenium, ... )
The following might be a **stupid** approach (for 2.7, i got not py3 + pyv8 installed).

```
import PyV8
jsCtx = PyV8.JSContext()
jsCtx.enter()

jsCtx.eval('var navigator = { "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3" }')
JsFilledJSON = """dataLayer = [
    {
        "site": {
            "isMobile": false,
            "source": (function() {
                var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLocaleLowerCase();
                var source = "web";
                resultMatch = userAgent.match(/\[olx-source\/(\w+);/);
                if (resultMatch) {
                    [, source] = resultMatch;
                }
                return source;
            })()
        },
        "page": {
            "pageType": "ad_detail",
            "detail": {
                "parent_category_id": "2000",
                "category_id": "2020",
                "state_id": "2",
                "region_id": "31",

                "ad_id": "354269527",
                "list_id": "295567499",
                "city_id": "9190",
                "zipcode":"32146045",

            }
        }
    }
]
"""

x = jsCtx.eval("JSON.stringify(%s)" % JsFilledJSON.decode('utf-8'))
print json.dumps(json.loads(x), indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

Returns:

```
[
    {
        "page": {
            "detail": {
                "ad_id": "354269527", 
                "category_id": "2020", 
                "city_id": "9190", 
                "list_id": "295567499", 
                "parent_category_id": "2000", 
                "region_id": "31", 
                "state_id": "2", 
                "zipcode": "32146045"
            }, 
            "pageType": "ad_detail"
        }, 
        "site": {
            "isMobile": false, 
            "source": "web"
        }
    }
]
```

But you can execute the JS-JSON with PyV8 or any other python to avascript wrapper. Binaries are at [github](https://github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries).